# Controller integration tests lose the session after follow_redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, controller-tests

When testing a rails 7 controller everything works splendidly until I get a redirect and then execute a `follow_redirect!`.  At this point the session mysteriously disappears and my tests can no longer continue...very limiting.

Very dumbed down, hypothetical example:

```
post some_url, params { yada: 'foo' }
assert_not_nil session[:yada]
assert_redirect some_redirect_url
follow_redirect!
assert_not_nil session[:yada] # This assertion fails, the session is gone
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Check to see if you're using `:null_store` for your `config.cache_store` setting in tests.  If so switch the config line to:
`config.cache_store = :memory_store`

After MUCH debugging and consternation, I was finally able to track down the issue. In the `test.rb` rails configuration file the `config.cache_store` setting was set to `:null_store`. Swapping this out for `:memory_store` fixed the issue and all was well again.  Worked like a charm...but took several hours to finally track down.